# Spike on graph generated

Tags: operational-amplifier

I had draw a DAC by using an adder circuit.Can i know why there is spikes on the graph generated?[image]

[image]

Comment: Having pins floating is often not the best thing to do. You might want to make the .asc file available for people to check.

Comment: Can i know how to upload the asc file?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I do not see any floating pins, Va - Vd are connected to one summation point. Now that I write this I realize that this is odd and not allowed in the circuit simulator I use (Cadence Spectre) as Va - Vd are all the same node! So why not simply draw them all as one node to make things more clear?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: look at the opamps, there ar two nodes not connected.

Comment: @PlasmaHH indeed, I didn't see that. Those are for frequency compensation so it might help to put a 100 pF capacitor between those 2 pins (the unused ones of the opamps) to better control teh bandwidth of the opamps which might help with the spikes in the simulation.

Answer (score 3):

Before posting such question its actually a good idea to isolate the problem. For that you should throw away all but the resistor ladder, and you can see the same problem.

If you now zoom in at the point of one of the spikes, and show all voltages of your voltage sources, you will notice that the source that ramps down only starts doing so once the others are ramped up.

As Trevor says, this is more or less an inherent property/problem of resistor ladder based DAC designs and will happen to a degree on real implementations too, as the timing of the switches will never be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is a common and irritating feature of DACs in general and is prevalent in simulators.

The issue is the simultaneous change of the bits in the presented DAC digital value. During that change, the resultant presented value can be any combination of the bits that change during the propagation delay.

Theoretically a simulator should be synchronous to the set data parameters, but as Andy mentions it really depends on how granular the simulator takes it's samples. Simulators like SPICE tend to sample in a reactionary sample rate based on what is changing so can present rather more spurious results as you have indicated. How much the simulator demonstrates the effect is dependent on the granularity of the simulation rate. By messing with the simulator granularity you can mask the effect, but that is actually a bad thing.

Since your real world DAC design will have propagation delay differences bit-to-bit, those spikes will be real and will be propagated through to the op-amp, and beyond if the op-amp is fast enough. Your circuit should be designed to limit the response time/slew rate to block that.

For a DAC design that is low frequency, such as setting some reference value, you can simply filter out the switching frequency. For something that is expected to output some waveform closer to the sample rate you need to synchronise the output to the data rate using a sample and hold circuit on the output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdAeC1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It isn't the simulation granularity, it is that for his setup the ramp down happens after the ramp up, its really a "pin timing" issue.

Comment: @PlasmaHH yes I meant, how much the simulator demonstrates the effect is dependent on that. By messing with the simulator granularity you can mask the effect, but that is actually a bad thing. \I should say that in the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of most SPICE simulators especially when a value for maximum time duration is not specified. I see ".tran 10" so you haven't specified a maximum timestep.

Try making this maybe 1 us and see what happens. Sure it will be slower in the transient analysis but it should improve. It wouldn't hurt to place a 1nf capacitor from inverting input to ground too - if you were making a real circuit with really fast edges on the inputs you might do this. Alternatively slow down the rise and fall times of the generators.

You are also using an old op-amp that requires (in some applications) the addition of a compensation capacitor. This might be the problem but certainly timestep issues and SPICE nuances quite commonly produce spikes like these.

Comment: Will try thanks ! I'm quite new to this topics and try to figure out how everything works

Comment: I do not think slowing down the rise-fall-times will help. That will just make the spikes shorter but wider, more rounded and noticeable.

Comment: @Trevor_G I'm sure the OP is keen to try out any suggestions! But a brave thing to say LOL.

Comment: This isn't really a matter of the simulation granularity or rise times. Due to the pulse setup, the voltage ramps down at the point of time the the other voltages are already ramped up.